# GLES20.glUniform4fv is giving GL_INVALID_OPERATION (1282)

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am having some problems uploading a small vector of `vec4`s to the GPU. I have boiled this problem down to the bare minimum code to throw an error.

Here is my Fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;
uniform vec4 test[5];
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = test[0]+test[1]+test[2]+test[3]+test[4];
}
```

And the vertex shader is trivial:

```
attribute vec4 vPosition;        
void main(){
    gl_Position = vPosition;
}
```

Here is the code that tries to upload the `vec4` vector:

```
    float[] testBuffer = new float[4*5];
    // Fill with 1/5s for now
    Arrays.fill(testBuffer, 0.2f);

    // Get the location
    int testLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "test");
    checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation test");

    // Upload the buffer
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(testLoc, 5, testBuffer, 0);
    checkGlError("glUniform4fv testBuffer");
```

The error is found on the second call to `checkGlError()`, and the error code is GL_INVALID_OPERATION.

I've read the documentation [on glUniform](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml) and all of the sizes and types appear to be correct. `testLoc` is a valid location handle, and I have no errors when uploading the fragment and vertex shader code.

I just can't see what I'm doing wrong! Any ideas?

--UPDATED

Comment: Make sure that your shader hasn't been optimized too much during compilation, so that test[] has become a single vec4 as you only use the first item.

Comment: Thanks Jave, but I'm pretty sure that's not the problem, as I've tried uploading the vector with all different sizes (including 1), and nothing has worked so far. I've even tried using a scalar `vec4` and using `glUniform4f()` to upload a single set of values. That fails too.

Comment: you should try to read from all positions as well as upload to. The shader-compiler only looks at what you use in the shader and removes anything that is not used there.

Comment: Thanks again Jave, I have tried editing the code to use all vector values (OP updated), but I still get the same error at the same place :-(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [`glUniform`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml) documentation:

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if there is no current program
>   object

Make sure your shader is currently bound/used when calling `glUniform` (`glUseProgram` has been called with the corresponding shader program handle). The uniform keeps its value when unbinding the shader (e.g. `glUseProgram(0)`), but the program has to be active when setting the uniform value.

Comment: That's the one! Thanks Christian, I thought I was going mad!

Comment: Thank you for ending my debug suffering!